# Search Engine: Using LSI (LSA) to enable a search in 2 languages when it is assumed that the query is only in one language

Tags: search-engine, pseudocode, lsa

I have a question about `latent semantic indexing`,

Suppose I have set of documents collected is in `English` and `Spanish`. And I have a translation table is attached for you. The translation table is not subject to the `search engine`.

The words between the languages are not the same. However, sometimes there are words that are completely identical in the two languages for example: Actor, Hostpital, General and more.

I want to write a `pseudo code` or give an explanation how you to use `LSI` to enable a search in both languages when it is assumed that the query is only in one of the languages.

Comment: This question is very broad.  I can imagine an entire book explaining how LSI is implemented with a chapter about languages.

Comment: I will be glad to get a link to that chapter, or get an explanation